# AWS YAML Invalid bucket policy syntax

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I get the error message when trying to deploy this part:

```
  OutBucketPolicyCredentials:
    Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
    Properties:
      Bucket:
        Ref: "SnowflakeStagingBucket2"
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          -
            Action:
              - "s3:GetObject"
            Effect: "Allow"
            Resource:
              Fn::Join:
                - ""
                -
                  - "arn:aws:s3:::"
                  -
                    Ref: "SnowflakeStagingBucket2"
                  - "/*"
            Principal: "di-snowflake-shipper-ShipperRole-1AVH7OJ0CDNSY"
```

Why syntax error?

Comment: I assume `di-snowflake-shipper-ShipperRole-1AVH7OJ0CDNSY` is the IAM role, would you please try with 
Principal: 
   - AWS: 
        - "arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/di-snowflake-shipper-ShipperRole-1AVH7OJ0CDNSY"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comment removes formatting, so I just re-post here. I assume di-snowflake-shipper-ShipperRole-1AVH7OJ0CDNSY is the IAM role, would you please try with the below snippet.

```
 Principal:
    AWS:
       - "arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/di-snowflake-shipper-ShipperRole-1AVH7OJ0CDNSY"
```

Comment: The CloudFormation Designer doesn't complain about that.  Thankyou.